# Why does calling git rev-list give different results from python Popen vs bash command line?

Tags: python, git, bash

I'm trying to get a list of all commands in my master branch programmatically.  I'm running `git rev-list --full-history master | wc -l` on bash and I get a 15272 objects, but when I call `subprocess.Popen(['git', 'rev-list', '--full-history', 'master'])` I only get 9273.

```
data = Popen(['git', 'rev-list', '--full-history', 'master'],
              stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]  # Grab STDOUT
commits = data[:-1].split('\n')
```

Why would I get significantly different results from a script than from the commandline?

Second, does this command do what I think it's doing? I.e. all commits that are in the master branch.

Comment: how do you read the result? Is it possible, that the result is buffered and you get just one buffer long (or you fill all memory with the buffer before reading it)? Can you show us the code in python?

Comment: what does `out = subprocess.check_output(...` show?

Comment: I'm working in python 2.6, so I don't have checkout_output.

Comment: Does your command-line behavior change when it's piping to somewhere? Even just putting `| cat` on the end will make stdout no longer a TTY. At a minimum that turns off the built-in pager for most git commands; whether it does anything else is locally defined.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I've been piping it to wc -l. I've edited it.

Comment: I've also tried calling it as a subprocess in bash `echo \`git rev-list --full-history master\` | wc -l ` and I get the same result.